# Editar registros en mysql con php mediante ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

Utilizo este formulario **extras_part.php**:

```
<form name="federal" action="" onsubmit="federal(); return false">
    <input type="hidden" name="federalid" value="<?php echo $mostrar_extras['extras_id']; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="federaluid" value="<?php echo $civiles_id; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="federalestado" value="<?php echo $mostrar_extras['extras_federal']; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="federalpeligroso" value="<?php echo $mostrar_extras['extras_peligroso']; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="federalcod9" value="<?php echo $mostrar_extras['extras_cod9']; ?>" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Federal (<?php echo $mostrar_extras['extras_federal']; ?>)</button>
</form>
```

Este el es PHP **extras_federal.php**:

```
<?php include_once 'db_cep.php';
    $id = $_GET['federalid'];
    $uid = $_GET['federaluid'];
    $estado = $_GET['federalestado'];
    $peligroso = $_GET['federalpeligroso'];
    $cod9 = $_GET['federalcod9'];
    $federalnum = $estado++;
    $sql_federal = "REPLACE INTO cep.extras (extras_id, extras_uid, extras_federal, extras_peligroso, extras_cod9) VALUES ('$id', '$uid', '$federalnum', '$peligroso', '$cod9')";
    mysqli_query($con_cep, $sql_federal);
?>
```

Esta es la función que envía los datos **ajax.js**:

```
function federal(federalid, federaluid, federalestado, federalpeligroso, federalcod9) {

    ajax = objetoAjax();

    ajax.open("GET", "extras_federal.php?federalid="+federalid+"&federaluid="+federaluid+"&federalestado="+federalestado+"&federalpeligroso="+federalpeligroso+"&federalcod9="+federalcod9);
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (ajax.readyState == 4) {
            actualizarExtras();
        }
    }

    ajax.send(null)
    }

function actualizarExtras() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#consultaextras').load('extras_part.php');
    });
}
```

Cuando uso el botón, se actualiza la página y se queda la dirección con:

> ?federalid=1&federaluid=1&federalestado=0&federalpeligroso=0&federalcod9=0

Los datos que salen en esa dirección son correctos, pero no ejecuta el php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes cambiar el boton de tipo submit por button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light" onclick="federal();"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Federal (<?php echo $mostrar_extras['extras_federal']; ?>)</button>
```

Así no se dispara el evento de submit y por consiguiente no debes lidiar con el return false, simplemente agregas la función `federal` al evento click del boton.

El formulario queda sin el evento:

```
<form name="federal">
```

Answer (score 0):

Con el aporte anterior de zerocool y un poco más de búsqueda, está solucionado y queda de la siguiente manera.

**extras_part.php** | Ya no existe el formulario, simplemente un botón con la tag *onclick* con los datos a enviar dentro de la función:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light" onclick="federal(<?php echo $civiles_id; ?>, <?php echo $mostrar_extras['civiles_federal']; ?>);"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Federal (<?php echo $mostrar_extras['civiles_federal']; ?>)</button>
```

---

**extras_federal.php** | El error estaba en utilizar *REPLACE INTO* en lugar de *UPDATE*, finalmente queda de la siguiente forma y funciona perfectamente:

```
<?php include_once 'db_ayto.php';
    $uid = $_GET['federaluid'];
    $estado = $_GET['federalestado'];
    $federalnum = $estado+1;
    $sql_federal = "UPDATE ayto.civiles SET civiles_federal = $federalnum WHERE civiles_id = $uid";
    mysqli_query($con_ayto, $sql_federal);
?>
```

---

**ajax.js** | La función para enviar los datos, ahora envia menos datos, ya que al cambiar la sentencia para introducir las variables en la base de datos no son necesarios.

```
function federal(federaluid, federalestado) {

  ajax = objetoAjax();

  ajax.open("GET", "extras_federal.php?federaluid="+federaluid+"&federalestado="+federalestado);
  ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (ajax.readyState == 4) {
      actualizarExtras();
    }
  }

  ajax.send(null)
}

function actualizarExtras() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#consultaextras').load('extras_part.php');
  });
}
```

---

Gracias por contestar, a partir de esa respuesta puede solucionar lo demás.